# Do not send me notifications Alert Email Prestashop by ERP

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem with the Alert email module, I have it installed in Prestashop 1.7.5 where users can register for notifications when the product has stock. The stock is loaded by an ERP, when the stock is added auntomatically, this notification is not sent, but if I go in the backoffice to the product file in the and keep, if it sends this notification.
Do you know what I have to configure or what function should I call to be updated automatically by the ERP? Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrestaShop works with hooks, I guess you are changing now the stock directly in the database. You need use the native PrestaShop method to change it:

```php
StockAvailable::setQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $quantity);
```

This will trigger automatically the hook `actionUpdateQuantity`, which the Mail Alerts module use to notify in the stock movements.